# Show that $T(X) = \min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a sufficient statistic using the factorisation theorem.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $g(x)$ be a positive integrable function on $(0,\infty)$. Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are random independent variables with common density $$f(x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx}\mathbb{1}_{[\theta,\infty)}(x)$$

**Exercise:** Show that $T(X) = \min(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a sufficient statistic using the factorisation theorem.

*What I've tried:* To show that $T(X)$ is sufficient I need to write $f(X\mid\theta)$ in the form of the factorisation theorem $$f(x\mid\theta) = g_\theta(T(X))h(x)$$

I have that $f(x\mid\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^n\dfrac{g(x)}{\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx}\mathbb{1}_{[\theta,\infty)}(x)$. If $X_{(1)} \geq \theta$, then every $X_i \geq \theta$, so we can replace the indicator function so that it only depends on $X_{(1)}$, we get $f(x\mid\theta) = \prod_{i = 1}^n\dfrac{g(x)}{\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx}\mathbb{1}_{\{X_{(1)}\geq\theta\}}$. Unfortunately, I don't see how I can make the $\int_\theta^\infty$ part a function of $X_{(1)}$ alone. I have $h(x) = \prod_{i = 1}^n g(x)$, but I can't find the right way to formulate $g(X)$.

**Question:** How do I solve this exercise, as indicated, using the factorisation theorem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$f(x_i;\theta) = \left\{ \begin{matrix}\frac{g(x_i)}{\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(t)dt} & \text{if $x \ge \theta$;}\\0 & \text{if $ x_i < \theta $.} \end{matrix}\right.$$
Consequently,
$$f(x_i;\theta) = \frac{g(x_i)}{l(\theta)} 1_{\{x_i\ge \theta \}},$$
where $l(\theta)=\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(t)dt$ is a function of $\theta$ only (i.e. it does not depend on $x_i$).
Therefore,
$$f(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n;\theta) = \color{red}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i)\right)} \color{blue}{\frac{1}{{l(\theta)}^n}\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1_{\{x_i\ge \theta \}}}.$$
Since
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} 1_{\{x_i \ge \theta\}} = 1_{\min\{x_i\}\ge \theta},$$

$$f(\theta|x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = \color{red}{h(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)}\color{blue}{g_{\theta}(\min\{x_i\})},$$
where
$$\color{red}{h(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i)},$$
and
$$\color{blue}{g_\theta(T(X)) = \frac{1}{{l(\theta)}^n}1_{\{T(X) \ge \theta\}}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, the factorisation theorem states that iff $T(X)$ is sufficient, you can write $f(X\mid\theta, T) = g_\theta(T(X))h(x)$. It doesn't say anything about writing $f(\theta\mid X)$ that way right?

Comment: @titusAdam It doesn't make any difference in the calculations. If you want, you can replace $f(\theta| x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n)$ with $f(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_2; \theta)$.

Comment: You say that $f(x_i;\theta) = \dfrac{g(x_i)}{\int_\theta^\infty g(t)dt}$ if $x_i\geq\theta$. I think this is incorrect! $\int_\theta^\infty g(t)dt\neq \int_\theta^\infty g(x_i)dx$ for $x_i\neq x_{(1)}$

Comment: @titusAdam Note that $x$ in $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$ is a dummy variable, and $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt$.

Comment: Why is $x$ a dummy variable? Suppose that your sample exists of two values, $X_1$ and $X_2$. Furthermore, suppose that $g(X_1) = 5$ and $g(X_2) = 10$. Then $\int_a^b g(X_1)dx = 5b - 5a$ and $\int_a^b g(X_2) dx = 10b - 10a$. If $a \neq b$ then $5b - 5a \neq 10b - 10a$.

Comment: @titusAdam Suppose $g(x)=x$. If someone asks you what is $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt$, what will be your answers? Also, observe that $\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx$ is not a function of $x$ at all! It just depends on $a$ and $b$. In your case, $\int_{\theta}^{\infty}g(x) dx$ is a function of $\theta$ *only*.

Comment: Sure if you *suppose* that $g(x) = x$ then $\int_a^bg(x)dx = \int_a^bg(t)dt$. But that's my objection; we don't know whether $g(X_{(1)}) = g(X_{(2)})$. I'm really trying to understand you and I believe that you're right, but how can I just "observe" that $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is not a function of x at all, if $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ possibly has a different values for different $x_i$. Furthermore, $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is part of the common density $f(x)$ which depends on $x$. If you have the time; could you explain in your answer why $\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx$ is not a function of $x$ but of $\theta$...

Comment: ... as I find it just as reasonable/logical to say that $\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx$ is not a function of $\theta$ but of $x$?

Comment: @titusAdam Let's make a substitution in $\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(x) dx$. That is, put $t= x$. Do you agree that, with the substitution $t=x$, $$\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(x) dx = \int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(t) dt?$$
If yes, can you observe that the R.H.S. does not contain $x$ at all! So do you agree that $\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(t) dt$ is not a function of $x$? If yes, then $\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(x) dx = \int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(t) dt$ implies that $\int_{\theta}^{\infty} g(x) dx$ is not a function of $x$ .

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why this is correct. Suppose we make a different substitution, we put $\theta = t$.  We have that $$\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx = \int_t^\infty g(x) dx.$$ You could then ask me the same question: do you agree that $\int_t^\infty g(x)dx$ is not a function of $\theta$? If yes then $\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx = \int_t^\infty g(x)dx$ implies that $\int_\theta^\infty g(x)dx$ is not a function of $\theta$.

Comment: @titusAdam I recommend you to go through [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) and [dummy variables in integration](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html). Hopefully, that will answer your questions.